# ios Podcasts on Andriod. Easy?

Tags: ios

I need to upgrade my smart phone.  I hate iTunes but love my podcasts.  Can I easily access my Podcasts with Andriod?   I asked this question at the ATT place and they said a curt, "no".

I don't believe them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of podcasting apps on google play store. For a very good free version Try player.fm, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fm.player they have a great podcasting app. You can try to search their catalog for your podcasts or add them manually using the itunes link.
You can also In iTunes Desktop, open Podcasts and then choose File > Library > Export playlist, then select OPML format. save it somewhere and transfer to your device and import this file to Player.fm app.